# empty section (header view) with no cell in fetch result controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, core-data

I am looking for a way to create an empty section with no cell.
I found this article that does it but it was too complicated and couldn't figure it out.[here](http://www.iosnomad.com/blog/2014/8/6/swift-nsfetchedresultscontroller-trickery)

I have two entities called category and book
each category can have many books but also it can have no books
how can I make it work?
here's how I fetch data

```swift
lazy var fetchResultController: NSFetchedResultsController<Book> = {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Book> = Book.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Book.name), ascending: false)]

        let fetchResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.persistentContainer.managedContext, sectionNameKeyPath: #keyPath(Book.category.name), cacheName: nil)

        fetchResultController.delegate = self

        return fetchResultController
    }()
```

here's the tableView data source

```swift
extension MainVC: UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        guard let sections = fetchResultController.sections else {
            return 0
        }
        return sections.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        guard let section = fetchResultController.sections?[section] else{return 0}

       return section.numberOfObjects
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ID.TableView.mainPage) as! BookCell
        let book = fetchResultController.object(at: indexPath)

        cell.nameLbl.text = book.name

        return cell
    }
}
```

here's the tableView Delegate

```swift
extension MainVC: UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        guard let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: ID.TableView.mainPageHeader) as? ProjectsHeaderView else{ return UIView() }

        let section = fetchResultController.sections?[section]


        header.label.text = section?.name
        header.delegate = self

        return header
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the count of your books array and populate the table view cells accordingly.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return booksArray.count > 0 ? booksArray.count : 1
    } else {
        return categoryArray.count
    }
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0 :
        if booksArray.count > 0 {
              let cell : YourBooksCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "identifier", for: indexPath) as! YourBooksCell
                  return cell
              } else {
                  let cell : YourEmptyCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "identifier", for: indexPath) as! YourEmptyCell
                            return cell
              }
    default:
        let cell : YourCategoryCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YourCategoryCell", for: indexPath) as! YourCategoryCell
        return cell
    }


}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        if booksArray.count > 0 {
            return 250
        } else {
            return 100 // height for your empty cell
        }
    } else {
        return 100 // your category cell height
    }
}
```

1. so in numberOfRowsInSection, we check whether the booksArray.count is 0 or not. if it is zero, we return 1 row. This 1 row will be your empty row.
2. in your cellForRowAt function, we again check if the booksarray is 0 or not. if it is zero, we return the empty cell else we return your bookscell
3. In heightForRowAt, if your booksArray count is not zero, make the height equal to your  books cell. Else, return the height of your empty cell.

Comment: i'm using fetchResultController so i don't have an array. and i need the category to be my headerview

Comment: you can use fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.count to count the total number of rows